# Html table tag does not exists on aspx page of the displayed Html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

On aspx page I have a div tag.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Reports.aspx.cs" Inherits="GOSCCMWeb.Reports" EnableViewState="true" %>
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <script src="Scripts/Reports.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div class="mainHeader">
        <label for="from">From</label>
        <input type="text" id="from" name="from" />
        <label for="to">To</label>
        <input type="text" id="to" name="to" />
        <label></label>
        <input type="button" value="Filter" onclick=" javascript:GetFilterData(); " />
    </div>
    <div id="divFilteredResults"></div>
</asp:Content>
```

In Report.js is function to render HTML table. It is getting displayed on aspx page properly.

But when I do view source code I do not see HTML table tag rendered. I need the table tag to present on aspx page because I am parsing the html table for export functionality. I am stuck. Any help appreciated.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: "{from: '" + from + "', to: '" + to + "', type: '" + type + "'}",
    url: "../GOSCCMWS.asmx/GetFilteredData",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        $('#divFilteredResults').html(data.d);

    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        $('#divFilteredResults').html(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: `dataType: "json",` You are expecting json data, why do you think it will spit out in table format ?

Comment: you are mixing things up, an 'aspx' page is a pre-compiled code, when client requests this page, the asp.net application compiles your page and renders the relevant html/javascript/css and sends it to the user. only there, on clientside(frontend) the file `Reports.js` is being executed and the table is rendered. you need to elaborate on the 'i am parsing the html table' in order for us to help you. where and how are you parsing the table, and where exactly its not shown?

Comment: Your client ID's likely aren't what you think they are. When ASP.NET renders the response to the client, the ID's can change. Therefore, set the ClientIdMode to Static for any controls that your JavaScript will be referring to by ID.

Comment: $('#divFilteredResults').html(data.d);
My expectation was it will spit out table tags inside the div element. I am using HtmlAgilityPack in .net to parse the html table so that I can export the table to excel using ClosedXml

Comment: Change the `dataType`

Comment: Changed dataType : 'html', but it is not working. I do not see any data. Earlier the table is getting displayed but I can not find html tag in the rendered aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

`dataType : 'html',` instead of `dataType : 'json',`.

**Datatype in ajax - tells the server what kind of response it will accept in return.**

So your call becomes:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   data: "{from: '" + from + "', to: '" + to + "', type: '" + type + "'}",
   url: "../GOSCCMWS.asmx/GetFilteredData",
   dataType: "html",
   success: function (data) {
       $('#divFilteredResults').html(data.d);

   },
   error: function (xhr, status, error) {
       $('#divFilteredResults').html(xhr.responseText);
   }
});
```